# Sort listview with array adapter

Tags: android, listview, sorting

I have a listview connected to a custom array adapter. This list shows information received by a TCP connection which changes the dataSet...

I am able to sort the listview with `sort (Comparator<? super T> comparator)`, but when the dataSet is changed, the listview is no more sorted...

I can use `sort ()` every time the dataSet is changed, but I think this is not the best option...

How can I do that? Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

I am having problems in implementing the solutions presented...

**MyComparatorB.java**

```
public class MyComparatorB implements Comparator<DeviceB> {

private byte orderType;

public MyComparatorB(byte type) {

    this.orderType = type;

}

public int compare(DeviceB lhs, DeviceB rhs) {

    int res = 0;
    if (orderType == SortType.ALPHA) {
            res = (lhs.getName()).compareTo(rhs.getName());
        }
        else if (orderType == SortType.LAST_ACT) {
            res = (rhs.getTime().getTime()).compareTo(lhs.getTime().getTime());
        }
        return res;
    }

}
```

**Snippet of my customArrayAdapter.java**

```
    @Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
}


//-----------Order the content of the arrayAdapter------------//
public void sort(byte sortType) {

    super.sort(new MyComparatorB(sortType));
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**In my MyActivity.java**

```
myDevAdapter.sort(SortType.ALPHA);
```

When I am debugging, the method `super.sort(new MyComparatorB(sortType));` is called and the constructor of MyComparatorB is called too. But the method `compare(DeviceB lhs, DeviceB rhs)` is never called and my arrayList is not sorted...
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: why you don't use ArrayList and sort the array and restore array list!

Comment: I think you should sort your array and call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: @amp : What is SortType here?

Comment: @YuDroid: It is just a class where I define the possible types of sorting. Like: `public class SortType{
    public final static int ALPHA= 1;
    public final static int LAST_ACT= 2;}`

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I guess you need to override **notifyDataSetChanged** method in your adapter and perform sorting right before calling its *super*. See below:

```
@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    //do your sorting here

    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Doing so will sort the list whenever you call `notifyDataSetChanged` method to refresh list items. Otherwise, feed a sorted List/array to your adapter.

---

Or more preferably, use the [`sort`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#sort%28java.util.Comparator%3C?%20super%20T%3E%29) method available in your adapter to get the job done.

```
adapter.sort(new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String lhs, String rhs) {
        return lhs.compareTo(rhs);   //or whatever your sorting algorithm
    }
});
```

Comment: the only way is call the `super.sort(comparator)` method every time the dataSet is changed?

Comment: yes, add this before calling super.notifyDataSetChanged, so that your data is sorted everytime

Comment: The .sort function automatically calls notifyDataSetChanged, so if you use this code with the built-in sort, you'll get into an infinite loop and overflow your stack.

Only do this if you're managing the list yourself, but most people using an Array Adapter aren't doing that.

Answer (score 4):

- Store data to an ArrayList
- Attach Array to Adapter
- Sort array and assign to itself
- Use notifyDataSetChanged() to refresh Adapter

Answer (score 4):

This works for me

```
@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    this.setNotifyOnChange(false);

    this.sort(new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String lhs, String rhs) {
            return lhs.compareTo(rhs);
        }
    });

    this.setNotifyOnChange(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Per elBradford's comment concerning the potential for a stack overflow resulting from the notifyDataSetChanged() approach, I ended up overriding the ArrayAdapter's add() method instead to ensure that the items maintain a sorted consistency when added one by one. (when calling addAll() I am sorting the items prior to; but I imagine you could override addAll() as well).

```
    @Override
    public void add(ListThing object) {
        super.add(object);
        this.sort(ListThing.sComparator);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since is the Adapter filling the ListView, the only way is to pass the data object in a sorted way.

Answer (score 0):

Once the listView is sorted, call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() from your activity.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [waqaslam](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9906539/6871241) and [KristianR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28274362/6871241)'s answer :

```
@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    this.setNotifyOnChange(false);

    this.sort(new Comparator<String>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
            return s1.compareTo(s2);
        }
    });

    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    this.setNotifyOnChange(true);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize ArrayAdapter and declare that we’re converting Strings into Views

```
val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(
            requireActivity(),
            R.layout.item_sample,
            R.id.tv_item_sample,
            samplesArray
)
```

Set the Adapter to the ListView, using setAdapter()

```
binding.lvSample.adapter = arrayAdapter
```

Perform sort and update the adapter.

```
arrayAdapter.sort { lhs, rhs -> lhs!!.compareTo(rhs!!) }
arrayAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(true)
```