# Sorting a list with integers android

Tags: android, sorting

Should I use the comparable or comparator when I want to sort my list based on my own personal object? 
should I use the collection operation in my recycler view adapter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort listview with array adapter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906464/sort-listview-with-array-adapter)

Comment: have you tried using [Google search](https://www.google.de/?gws_rd=ssl#q=how+to+sort+an+arraylist+in+java)?

Comment: yes I tried. nevermind. I just needed an example. I cant delete this post anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Is it a list of integers (as you specify in your title)?

you can use `Arrays#sort`

```
Arrays.sort(someArray, new Comparable<Integer>() {
    public int compare(Integer a, Integer b) {
        return a.compareTo(b);
    }
});
```

Comment: you don't need a `Comparator` (not a Comparable either) to sort integers.

Comment: also, it seems you are confusing array with list.

Comment: well basically I have also text, but I want to sort the list by the integers that I have. ive seen this code you posted but I didn't know where should I use it..

Comment: When you add items to your adapter, add them to the stored list and re-sort it.

Answer (score 2):

If it's just a list of integers, and they are in for instance a List object, you don't have to use a comparator, unless you need to parse the integers as something other than plain numbers.

```
Collections.sort(myList);
```

If it's one of your own objects, look at Tyler Sebastians answer. Collections comes with a similar method for lists.

```
Collections.sort(myList, new MyComparator());
```