# Sort a FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I'm making an app that shows the days of the week coming from FireBase, the problem is that I have them messed up and I want them to be sorted.

I have searched in many places and put order with the sort method of the adapter:

> [Sort listview with array adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906464/sort-listview-with-array-adapter)

The problem is that I can not use this method because I use a FirebaseRecyclerAdapter which derives from an Adapter, which does not have the sort method.

At the end I was able to sort the data of the adapter but when I show it only the last element is shown and the previous one is not.

I put the code:

The adapter:

```
public class MyFireAdapterDiasFiestaRecyclerView extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<DiaFiestaMeta, MyFireAdapterDiasFiestaRecyclerView.MyFireViewHolder>
    implements View.OnClickListener {
private View.OnClickListener listener;
private List<DiaFiestaMetaFecha> dias;
private static List<TextView> views ;
private DiaFiestaMetaFecha fechaDia;

public MyFireAdapterDiasFiestaRecyclerView(Class<DiaFiestaMeta> modelClass, int modelLayout, Class<MyFireViewHolder> viewHolderClass, DatabaseReference ref) {
    super(modelClass, modelLayout, viewHolderClass, ref);
    dias = new ArrayList<>();
    views = new ArrayList<>();

}

@Override
public MyFireViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fila_diasfiesta_layout, viewGroup, false);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    MyFireViewHolder holder = new MyFireViewHolder(itemView);
    return holder;
}

public void setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (listener != null)
        listener.onClick(view);
}

@Override
protected void populateViewHolder(MyFireViewHolder viewHolder, DiaFiestaMeta modelo, int position) {
    fechaDia = new DiaFiestaMetaFecha(modelo.getUidDiaFiesta(), modelo.getTituloDiaFiesta());
    dias.add(fechaDia);
    if (this.getItemCount() == position + 1) {
        viewHolder.bindDatos(dias);
    }
}

public static class MyFireViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView textoTv;
    private int num;



    public MyFireViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textoTv = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTituloDiaFiesta);

        views.add(textoTv);

    }

    public void bindDatos(String titulo) {
        textoTv.setText(titulo);
    }

    public void bindDatos(List<DiaFiestaMetaFecha> dias) {
        burbuja(dias);
        for (int i = 0; i < dias.size(); i++) {
            views.get(i).setText(dias.get(i).getTituloDiaFiesta());
        }
    }


}
```

}

And the fragment where I use it:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    uidsFiestas = getUidsFiestas();
    //Por defecto mostramos la ultima fecha
    uidFiestaSeleccionada = getUltimaFiesta();
    adaptadorFiestas = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, uidsFiestas);
    //Ponemos el uidFiestaSeleccionada el primero para que nos lo muestre
    adaptadorFiestas.remove(uidFiestaSeleccionada);
    adaptadorFiestas.insert(uidFiestaSeleccionada,0);
    mDataBaseDiasFiestaSelRef = mDataBaseFiestasRef.child(uidFiestaSeleccionada).child("diasFiestas");
    adaptadorDiasFiestas = new MyFireAdapterDiasFiestaRecyclerView(DiaFiestaMeta.class, R.layout.fila_diasfiesta_layout, MyFireAdapterDiasFiestaRecyclerView.MyFireViewHolder.class, mDataBaseDiasFiestaSelRef);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fiestas_layout, container, false);

    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    spFiestas.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            TextView textoTv = (TextView) view;
            uidFiestaSeleccionada = textoTv.getText().toString();
            //fiestaSeleccionada = crearFiesta(uidFiestaSeleccionada);
            mDataBaseDiasFiestaSelRef = mDataBaseFiestasRef.child(uidFiestaSeleccionada).child("diasFiestas");
            adaptadorDiasFiestas = new MyFireAdapterDiasFiestaRecyclerView(DiaFiestaMeta.class, R.layout.fila_diasfiesta_layout, MyFireAdapterDiasFiestaRecyclerView.MyFireViewHolder.class, mDataBaseDiasFiestaSelRef);
            adaptadorViejoDiasFiestas = (MyFireAdapterDiasFiestaRecyclerView) recView.getAdapter();
            recView.setAdapter(adaptadorDiasFiestas);

            if (adaptadorViejoDiasFiestas!=null)
                adaptadorViejoDiasFiestas.cleanup();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
    spFiestas.setAdapter(adaptadorFiestas);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    recView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    manager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    recView.setLayoutManager(manager);
    recView.setAdapter(adaptadorDiasFiestas);
    return view;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: consider http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42249524/sorting-items-position-using-firebaserecycleradapter/42319463#42319463

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason only one item shows up is that you only call `bindViewHolder` conditionally:

```
if (this.getItemCount() == position + 1) {
    viewHolder.bindDatos(dias);
}
```

Remove that condition and the others will show up too.

To get a sorted and filtered result, you have to pass a query into the `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` constructor, where you are now passing in a `DatabaseReference`. So add a constructor to your adapter that takes a `Query`:

```
public MyFireAdapterDiasFiestaRecyclerView(
    Class<DiaFiestaMeta> modelClass, 
    int modelLayout, 
    Class<MyFireViewHolder> viewHolderClass, 
    Query query) {
    ...
```

And then invoke it with a query that orders and filters:

```
adapter = new MyFireAdapterDiasFiestaRecyclerView(
   DiaFiestaMeta.class,
   layout_that_you_use,
   MyFireViewHolder.class,
   ref.orderByChild("property_to_sort_and_filter_on").equalTo("value_to_filter_on")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done what you told me. For this I have included in my FireBase Database a field called "order". This field will be in which the nodes will be sorted:

```html
{
  "descripcion" : "desc1",
  "diasFiestas" : {
    "Domingo5deMarzo2017" : {
      "orden" : 4,
      "tituloDiaFiesta" : "Domingo 5 de Marzo",
      "uidDiaFiesta" : "Domingo5deMarzo2017"
    },
    "Jueves2deMarzo2017" : {
      "orden" : 1,
      "tituloDiaFiesta" : "Jueves 2 de Marzo",
      "uidDiaFiesta" : "Jueves2deMarzo2017"
    },
    "Jueves9deMarzo2017" : {
      "orden" : 8,
      "tituloDiaFiesta" : "Jueves 9 de Marzo",
      "uidDiaFiesta" : "Jueves9deMarzo2017"
    },
    "Lunes6deMarzo2017" : {
      "orden" : 5,
      "tituloDiaFiesta" : "Lunes 6 de Marzo",
      "uidDiaFiesta" : "Lunes6deMarzo2017"
    },
```

In my Fragment:

```
adaptadorDiasFiestas = new MyFireAdapterDiasFiestaRecyclerView(DiaFiestaMeta.class, R.layout.fila_diasfiesta_layout, MyFireAdapterDiasFiestaRecyclerView.MyFireViewHolder.class, mDataBaseDiasFiestaSelRef.orderByChild("orden"));
```

But it does not order anything